# isotope plugin auto height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a isotope filter plugin and have trouble getting the height to stay dynamic to the content. When it goes to bigger size-it's ok. But when I get from 3 rows of images to 1(for example), the height of a container change immediately, not dymanic. I googled everywhere, tried everything but the problem remains, unfortunately. I posted my site on github. Here you can see more detail of code: https://marcell123.github.io/marcell2.github.io/
https://github.com/Marcell123/marcell2.github.io

but I want my isotope filter plugin to work like here:
http://veented.info/waxom/home-portfolio-rev-slider/

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
    

   $('.portfolio-btn').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
   });

     // init Isotope
   var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({

   itemSelector:'.grid-item',
   percentPosition: true,
   masonry: {
    columnWidth: '.grid-item'
    }
   })
  });

})
```

```css
/*our latest project*/
section#our-latest-project {
 padding-top: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 h3 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #555555;
  line-height: 1.2;
 }
 p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
   color: #8c8c8c;
   width: 760px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   line-height: 1.75;
 }
}


.portfolio-menu {
 button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
 }
}

.single-portfolio-item {
 img {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
}

.grid-item {
 float: left;
}/*our latest project*/
section#our-latest-project {
 padding-top: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 h3 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #555555;
  line-height: 1.2;
 }
 p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
   color: #8c8c8c;
   width: 760px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   line-height: 1.75;
 }
}


.portfolio-menu {
 button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
 }
}

.single-portfolio-item {
 img {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
}

.grid-item {
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="our-latest-project">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h3>Our Latest Projects.</h3>
      <p>Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium.</p>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="portfolio-menu">
       <div class="button-group portfolio-btn">
         <button data-filter="*">show all</button>
         <button data-filter=".cat1">metal</button>
         <button data-filter=".cat2">transition</button>
         <button data-filter=".cat3">alkali  alkaline-earth</button>
         <button data-filter="cat4">not transition</button>
         <button data-filter=".cat5">metal but not transition</button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="grid">
      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item cat1">
       <div class="single-portfolio-item">
        <img src="images/phone.jpg" alt="phone" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item cat2 cat4">
       <div class="single-portfolio-item">
        <img src="images/phone.jpg" alt="phone" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item cat1 cat3">
       <div class="single-portfolio-item">
        <img src="images/phone.jpg" alt="phone" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item cat2 cat4">
       <div class="single-portfolio-item">
        <img src="images/open-book.jpg" alt="book-open" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item cat1">
       <div class="single-portfolio-item">
        <img src="images/phone.jpg" alt="phone" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item cat2 cat3">
       <div class="single-portfolio-item">
        <img src="images/bird.jpg" alt="bird" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item cat1 cat5">
       <div class="single-portfolio-item">
        <img src="images/mountain.jpg" alt="mountain" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item cat1 cat3">
       <div class="single-portfolio-item">
        <img src="images/scale.jpg" alt="scale" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after many useless attempts I made before to solve this issue, the problem was solved. I just added next section with it's own content. I suppose, that's because the height is calculating from the window/document. Because of that line $(document).ready(function().
Hope, this will help someone in future